# IE10 and ASP.NET 2.0 Button control

Tags: asp.net-2.0, internet-explorer-10

I'm Still stuck cause of IE 10.

On page_load I tried to set :

```
Button1.Enabled = false;
```

and **its not working only on IE10,** on other browsers it works amazing.

*Edit:*

I have already updated ie.browser file. [Fix for most of the IE10 problems]

What can be done to fix this issue. Please somebody help me!

Comment: Is this for a a web page? and are you talking about a serverside button control or a html button control?

Comment: Yes, Its for web page and server side Button control.

Comment: Please give me some idea's, what can be done? Any any input's are welcome and would be great.

Comment: When I tried it with a new asp.net 2.0 web site with just a ASP:button on a new page it worked fine. And I used the same code as you did. I use Win7 x64 and IE10 and VS2010 to test it out

Comment: When you view source in the browser, what do you see?  Is the button marked disabled in the HTML?

Comment: When I look at the button it is greyed/grayed out and disabled and in the source i see the following "<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" id="Button1" disabled="disabled" />"

Comment: Note: with ref to the source code below the ASP button is enabled to begin. If it was disabled at design time the code would read "<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="False" />"

Comment: @Emma If it still doesn't work for you, try to un-install (completely) your IE10 and then after a reboot re-install it again.

Comment: I have tried it, didn't help. But,Okay! I'll it again. Thanks. If anything else also can be done, Plz let me know.

Comment: @Zaf Khan:page viewsource: its showing disabled="disabled" for button, but its not reflected in UI [Like in grey color].

Comment: @Emma, Well that is strange indeed, Mmmmm I wonder, what version of VS are you using and which .NET frameworks do you have installed? Also i have added screen grabs of the button to show it is grayed out on my pc. and the .NET framework too to ensure you i tested it with the same.

Comment: I have VS Team System 2008, Development Edition with framework 2.0, But I'm testing it on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

Answer (score 0):

@Emma

This is the source code.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

  Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Button1.Enabled = False
  End Sub

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Ie version:

[image]

[image]

[image]